Can we do this approach using suitable RNAV instead of ADF/ DME,
KCEW has VOR-A approach. And this has NOTME FIX MINIMA, which requires ADF or DME. However, these ADF or DME are used to find NOTME FIX, (to detect direction of LOM or Distance). In other words ADF and DME are not used as lateral guidance. In this case, is it possible to use GPS as a suitable RNAV to identify NOTME FIX?


Yes. You need to be equipped with a VOR receiver and use it to monitor the final approach course guidance. But identifying other fixes with a suitable RNAV system is fine.
The exact rules for what you can and cannot do with a suitable RNAV system can be found in the AIM, currently under 1-2-3, "Use of Suitable Area Navigation (RNAV) Systems on Conventional Procedures and Routes."
